# alert window display extra text at the top

Tags: javascript

Wondering why Chrome displays extra text at the top of alert window:[alert window with extra text at the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtGmP.png)

Is there a way to remove those texts in Chrome? This seems only happen in Chrome.

Thanks,
Shawn

Answer (score 0):

Generally no, but there is an exception however it is only useful in a limited context:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIPromptService